# How can I map this matrix into another coordinate system, so it can be added to a second matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, mapping

I am trying to solve a problem which I may struggle to describe, so will attempt to describe with the aid of the following picture (please bear with me!):

[image]

I have two matrices which are defined on different coordinate spaces `(u,v)` for matrix A and `(x,y)` for matrix B. They have different grid sizes and different numbers of pixels. My goal is to apply a scaling factor `S` to the matrix A, and then to simply add it to matrix B. (For context, this is an optical imaging problem, where matrix A is located at an object plane, matrix B is located at an image plane, and S is the magnification).

So, I would like to create a new matrix C which is the equivalent of A but brought into the new coordinates (x,y). Matrix C should have the same number of rows and columns as B.

A minimum example of A and B is shown below, where the red dashed lines on the right illustrate the effective physical regions occupied by matrix A's pixels:

[image]

This is produced by the following code:

```matlab
%%% Inputs for matrix A %%%
M = 4; % num columns in matrix A
N = 4; % num rows in matrix A
du = 13; % horizontal size of a pixel in matrix A [mm]
dv = 13; % vertical size of a pixel in matrix A [mm]

%%% Set up matrix A %%%
Lu = (M-1)*du; % physical hor. coord. of centre of last pixel [mm]
Lv = (N-1)*dv; % physical ver. coord. of centre of last pixel [mm]
u = -Lu/2:du:Lu/2; % hor. coordinates for matrix A [mm]
v = -Lv/2:dv:Lv/2; % ver. coordinates for matrix A [mm]
A = zeros(N,M);
A(1,1) = 1; % Set a few values to 1 for testing
A(2,3) = 1;
A(3,4) = 1;

%%% Inputs for matrix B %%%
dx = 0.1; % grid step in matrix B [mm]
dy = 0.1; % grid step in matrix B [mm]
Lx = 6; % physical hor. coord. of centre of last pixel [mm]
Ly = 6; % physical ver. coord. of centre of last pixel [mm]

%%% Set up matrix B %%%
x = -Lx/2:dx:Lx/2;
y = -Ly/2:dy:Ly/2;
B = rand(length(y),length(x));

figure('color','w');
subplot(1,2,1);imagesc(u, v, A); axis equal tight;
subplot(1,2,2);imagesc(x, y, B); axis equal tight;

S = 1/20; % scale factor from matrix A's corrdinates to matrix B's

% C = ?
```

In this example, I have set the pixel size of matrix A to be 13mm, and the scaling factor to be 1/20. This means that in B's coordinates each pixel should be 13/20 = 0.65mm. This is bigger than the grid size dx=0.1mm, and so in this case the result should be that, after mapping, pixels should span multiple grid points. Any region outside the total extent of matrix A should be padded with zeros.

Is there a simple way (or built-in function) which would quickly generate matrix C in Matlab (ideally without using loops over each pixel, or interpolation)?

I can simply scale the coordinates, which matches the physical dimensions, but the matrices are still different number of rows and columns:

```
u_scaled = u*S;
v_scaled = v*S;
subplot(1,3,3);imagesc(u_scaled, v_scaled, A); axis equal tight;
```

[image]

Comment: Use kron() with your A matrix to scale it to the desired number of rows/columns.  Then add it to the appropriate submatrix of B.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but because the scaling factor is not always a nice multiple it didn't work properly (both the grid sizes du and dx can be funny numbers). Could you provide an example? I also need to achieve the padding when the scaled matrix outer dimensions are smaller than B's outer dimensions.

Comment: @bg2b I am also not sure how to obtain the size of the "submatrix of B", so I can calculate the scaling factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interp2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) or [griddedInterpolant](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html):

```
C = interp2(u, v, A, x * 20, y.' * 20, 'nearest', 0);
```

With some modification better result can be produced:

```
AA = padarray(A, [1 1], 0);
uu = [-du+u(1) u u(end)+du];
vv = [-dv+v(1) v v(end)+dv];
C = interp2(uu, vv, AA, x * 20, y.' * 20, 'nearest', 0);
```